# Reading rfid tag from USB

Tags: c++, c, usb, rfid, libusb

I want to capture data from an RFID Tag that is coming from my USB port.
My questions are as follows:-

1. Any suggestions of a software that can sniff this data from the USB port?
2. How do I receive this data and feed it into my C/C++ program?
3. And also any suggestions/links/books on how to code in C for 8051, as i intend to burn my program on the 8051 that is connected to the RFID?

Answer (score 0):

Check for an API from your reader. All USB work that I've done with "non-standard" hardware has been through a vendor-supplied driver / API.

Comment: @jasonbugfenter Thanks for the reply. What do you exactly mean by "non-standard" hardware? And did you use 8051 for your work?

Comment: My software interfaces with automated carousel shelving (a competitor of Remstar) as well as an automated locking cabinet (a competitor of Pyxis CII Safe) via USB. Not exactly a printer or cash drawer or anything that common. And no, I didn't use 8051; honestly, it sounds familiar but I'm not even sure I know what that is. lol